# Syntax Error in plot histogram python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

In the print statements and plot.hist command in the code below, python returns a statement saying the lines contain syntax errors. I'm pretty sure I have the right documentation, though, so maybe the indentations in the for loop preceding the statement are incorrect? Thank you!

```
import pyfits
import math 
import numpy 

hdulist = pyfits.open("VDGC_catalog_pPXF.fits")
catalog= hdulist[1].data[0]

zerr = []
verr = [] 

#loop to fill zerr with actual values 
for i in range(0, len(catalog)):
    if catalog[3][i] == 'GC' and catalog[4][i] == 'N' and catalog[10][i] == 1:
        zerr.append(catalog[9][i])

for i in range(0, range(zerr)):
    verr.append((zerr[i])*299792458

plot.hist(verr, bins = 100, color = "pink")

plt.show()
print "Done."
```

Comment: Can you post the produced error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(too much code; can not put this in a comment)

apart from the missing closing bracket in

```
for i in range(0, range(zerr)):
    verr.append((zerr[i])*299792458
```

the thing i could imagine you want to be doing would be

```
for zi in zerr:
    verr.append(zi*299792458)
```

and the more pythonic version of this is

```
verr = [zi*299792458 for zi  in zerr]
```